# TypeError ( 'module' object is not callable )

Tags: python, module, sikuli, callable

I have two Scripts. Script 1 is titled **schemeDetails**.The second script is a test script called **temporaryFile** that creates a schemeSetup object using the schemeSetup class which is within schemeDetails. Everything is hunky dory up to the point where I try to acess the method insertScheme which is within the schemeSetup Class.

I have imported the schemeDetails script using the following:

```
import schemeDetails
reload(schemeDetails)
from schemeDetails import *
```

I can create the schemeDetails Object and access its attributes

```
d = schemeDetails.schemeSetup() -- fine
print(d.scheme) -- fine
d.insertScheme() -- throws error
```

but trying to call the insertScheme function throws an error

I don't know why this is happening as the import statement looks above board to me. Any advice appreciated

```
from sikuli import *
import os

class schemeSetup(object):
    #Uses default values
    def __init__(
        self,
        scheme = "GM",
        cardNumber = "1234567A",
        month = "December",
        year = "2015",
        setSchemeAsDefault = True):

        #Provide default values for parameters
        self.scheme = scheme
        self.cardNumber = cardNumber
        self.month = month
        self.year = year
        self.setSchemeAsDefault = setSchemeAsDefault
        #schemeDetails is not a sub
        # class of patient. It is simply defined within the patient class 
        # - there is a huge difference. 

#====================================================#        
        #schemeDetails Function
    def insertScheme(self):
        print("insertScheme Works")    
        #r = Regions()
        #r.description("Patient Maintenance", "schemeDetails")
        #myRegion = r.createRegion()
        #myRegion.highlight(1)  

        #click(myRegion.find(insertSchemeButton))
        #click(myRegion.find(blankSchemeEntry))
        #type(self.scheme + Key.ENTER + Key.ENTER)           
        #type(self.cardNumber + Key.ENTER)
        #type(self.month + Key.ENTER)
        #type(self.year + Key.ENTER)
        #type(" ")
        #unticks HT link, HT linking should be in a separate function

#====================================================#           
        #schemeDetails Function
    def editScheme(self):
        print("editScheme Works")

#====================================================#        
    def deleteScheme(self):
        pass
#====================================================#
```

It may be of importance that calling either of the bottom functions does not produce an error. If I put print("Hello") under editScheme, and call that method using s.editScheme the program compiles but I get no output. If I run print(s.editScheme) it returns None

Comment: Why are you using all three of those statements for your import?

Comment: I thought it was necessary. I guess not! I had a feeling that was the case, I was just being unnecessarily thorough

Comment: You should only need one, yea. `import Patient` is safest. but you'll have to preface every `func()` in there, i.e. `Patient.func()`. `from Patient import *` is discouraged but usable if your project has a small scope, and you're only importing functions.

Comment: What is the error?  Please show us the traceback.  You may also want to look at PEP 8 (http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).  You're using a number of unpythonic naming conventions...and your classes should all inherit from object.

Comment: I use global variables in a few different classes, so I will use from xxx import * for those and try and keep it simple for the others

Comment: You should definitely not be using `from xxx import *` for global variables. That method will just take a "snapshot" of module `xxx` at the given time, which means that if `xxx` changes those global variables, the file you're importing to will never find out about it. This tripped me up a few times in the past.

Comment: also, `schemeDetails` is not a subclass of `patient`.  It is simply defined within the patient class - there is a huge difference.

Comment: The error given points to d.insertScheme() [error] script [ temporaryFile ] stopped with error in line 27
[error] TypeError ( 'module' object is not callable )

Comment: what does  `print d.insertScheme` output?

Comment: It gives the same error message

Comment: Please edit your error traceback into your question, with the exact formatting it uses.

Comment: Hi, I gave the error at the top of the edited post. Its still exactly the same problem - just tidied up

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems to be fixed now after changing the import format to this

```
    import schemeDetails 
    from schemeDetails import schemeSetup
    s = schemeDetails.schemeSetup()
```

Comment: If you use `from schemeDetails import schemeSetup`, all you need to do is run `s = schemeSetup()`.  As it is you can remove the from...import line